# Bower is failing with VS 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, bower

**Context:**

I am trying to use bower in my VS 2015 Update 2 ASP.NET 4.6 project. Bower was successfully(?) ***installed via npm under the project***. After creating an saving bower.json, there are error messages related to git. (see exhibit)

**Note:**

This is not the protocol change issue (git:// -> https://). ***The protocol is already https.***

**Question:**

How can I configure bower to work with my VS 2015 ASP Web application.

**bower output exhibit:**

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#*       not-cached https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.git#*
bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#*          resolve https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.git#*
bower modernizr#*                           not-cached https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#*
bower modernizr#*                              resolve https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#*
bower bootstrap#*                           not-cached https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower bootstrap#*                              resolve https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#*         checkout v3.2.6
bower modernizr#*                             checkout v3.3.1
bower bootstrap#*                             checkout v3.3.6
bower jquery-validation-unobtrusive#*          ECMDERR Failed to execute "git clone https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.git -b v3.2.6 --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #-532462766
```

Comment: Hello, are you creating bower.json file ?

Comment: Yes. That's why you are seeing the bower output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your git version (https://git-scm.com/), just download the latest binary, make sure VS is closed, and install.

Choose **Windows console** over MinTTY while installing (haven't tried the other way)

Then just launch VS and restore bower packages

This helped me solve the same exact error as yours (on VS 2015 Enterprise + ASP.NET Core RC1) while installing ASP.NET MVC 6 Boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

make sure a file exists in that dir with bower.json named ".bowerrc"

its contents should be:

{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}

this fixed it for me! :)

Comment: Thanks. The line exists, and the director also exists.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why this happens but this is how i solved it :

- **Install** standalone Git from http://git-scm.com/
- **Open** bash and **execute** to use https instead on git (firewall maybe blocking git protocol) :

  `git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`
- **Configure** Visual studio to use this new git tool instead :

  [image]
  **add** the last line and **uncheck** the old git command line.